# multiple mysql containers only one is working

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

What I am doing wrong? Only one is working, I am using phpmyadmin for accesing it, and in the log files I got this in all the others containers:

```
2021-02-19 16:13:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.

2021-02-19 16:13:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2021-02-19 16:13:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
```

And phpmyadmin says `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused` (only mysql1 is connection)

This is my `docker-compose`

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysql1:
        image: mysql:5.7.33
        container_name: mysql1
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db1
          MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root      
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_USER: db1      
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: db1      
          SERVICE_TAGS: dev
          SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
          - mysql1:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./etc/mysql/my1.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        networks:
          - app-network
    
      mysql2:
        image: mysql:5.7.33
        container_name: mysql2
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
          - "3307:3306"
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db2
          MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root      
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_USER: db2      
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: db2      
          SERVICE_TAGS: dev
          SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
          - mysql2:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./var/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
          - ./etc/mysql/my2.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
          - ./var/transit/:/var/transit
        networks:
          - app-network
    
      mysql3:
        image: mysql:5.7.33
        container_name: mysql3
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
          - "3308:3306"
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db3
          MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root      
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_USER: db3      
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: db3      
          SERVICE_TAGS: dev
          SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
          - mysql3:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./var/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
          - ./etc/mysql/my3.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
          - ./var/transit/:/var/transit
        networks:
          - app-network
    
      mysql4:
        image: mysql:5.7.33
        container_name: mysql4
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
          - "3309:3306"
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db4
          MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root      
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_USER: db4      
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: db4      
          SERVICE_TAGS: dev
          SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
          - mysql4:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./etc/mysql/my-4.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        networks:
          - app-network
    
      # PHPMYADMIN
      phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        environment:
         PMA_USER: root
         PMA_PASSWORD: root    
         PMA_HOSTS: mysql1,mysql2,mysql3,mysql4
         PMA_PORTS: 3306,3307,3308,3309
        links:
         - mysql1
         - mysql2
         - mysql3
         - mysql4
        restart: always
        ports:
         - 8080:80
        volumes:
         - phpmyadmin:/sessions
        networks:
          - app-network   
    
    
    #Docker Networks
    networks:
      app-network:
        driver: bridge
    #Volumes
    volumes:
      phpmyadmin:
        driver: local
      studioweb:
        driver: local
      sessions:
        driver: local
      mysql1:
        driver: local
      mysql2:
        driver: local    
      mysql3:
        driver: local
      mysql4:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Is there a block `version: '3.8' services:` top of yaml file?

Comment: 3, version.original question updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all use same network and port is used. It does not corrupt or show an error but not working. I added MYSQL_TCP_PORT to each service to work on different port(3307 not included) and it is working fine.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql1:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: mysql1
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db1
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: db1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db1
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3306
    volumes:
          - mysql1:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./etc/mysql/my1.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql2:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: mysql2
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3310:3310"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db2
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: db2
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db2
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3310
    volumes:
          - mysql2:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./var/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
          - ./etc/mysql/my2.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
          - ./var/transit/:/var/transit
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql3:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: mysql3
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3308:3308"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db3
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: db3
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db3
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3308
    volumes:
          - mysql3:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./var/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
          - ./etc/mysql/my3.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
          - ./var/transit/:/var/transit
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql4:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: mysql4
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3309:3309"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db4
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: db4
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db4
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3309
    volumes:
          - mysql4:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./etc/mysql/my-4.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

  # PHPMYADMIN
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
     PMA_USER: root
     PMA_PASSWORD: root
     PMA_HOSTS: mysql1,mysql2,mysql3,mysql4
     PMA_PORTS: 3306,3310,3308,3309
    links:
     - mysql1
     - mysql2
     - mysql3
     - mysql4
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 8080:80
    networks:
      - app-network


#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  phpmyadmin:
    driver: local
  studioweb:
    driver: local
  sessions:
    driver: local
  mysql1:
    driver: local
  mysql2:
    driver: local
  mysql3:
    driver: local
  mysql4:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try, but why I have to specify the ports? The mysql's ports are internal of the container, so AFAIK the internal can always be 3306, the "outside" must change

Comment: ok. is working. Don't know how, but it's working! thanks

Comment: Maybe it s caused they are in same network. Please mark as answer and close issue. Thank you.